# Cannot run the test example of sfPhpExcel

Tags: symfony-1.4, phpexcel

I have installed sfPhpExcelPlugin successfully and now I am trying to run an example as per the direction of symfony plugin's website.

I am getting this error, do you guys know how to solve it?

```
C:\wamp\www\orangehrm-3.01\symfony>php symfony plugins/sfPhpExcelPlugin/examples_1_2/01simple.php

Task "plugins/sfPhpExcelPlugin/examples_1_2/01simple.php" is not defined.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `php symfony` command you are trying to run Symfony task. Your example of sfPhpExcelPlugin is not a Symfony task. Try:

```
php plugins/sfPhpExcelPlugin/examples_1_2/01simple.php
```

And to see list of all available Symfony task type:

```
php symfony
```